# How to transfer all files from root account to another account?

Tags: files, root

I was new to Ubuntu and always had a bad habit of using the root account. How do I transfer my all files from the root account to another account? Overall, I just want the new account to be an exact replica of the root with all the files and obviously without the privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Habit of using root account is a very bad and dangerous practice (considering security and privacy of the system). Please avoid using root account unless required. Also don't make new account **exact replica** of the root account. Since all files in root account isn't meant for normal account. Instead identify which files you need to be in user account (normal account) and move that file and change its permissions using `chmod`.